# When I decrease the line-height on the tag the words overlap each other

Tags: html, css

I use these sizes for the text in my CSS but I am facing a problem with line height. I want to decrease the line height in CSS but when I use mark tag the words will be on each other. I have attached an image that shows the issue:

[image]

Code:

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 58px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0px 0px;
  line-height: 1em;
  font-family: "frutigerBold75";
}
```

```html
<h1><mark>Guidelines on Certification <br />and Grading</mark></h1>
```

Comment: Did you apply any css to the mark element?

Comment: What results are you expecting?

Comment: i don't need the words above each other when i use highlight yellow color @ArjanKnol

Comment: When run code snippet it runs fine???

Answer (score 2):

you should put desired `line-height` inside `mark`

*before*

```css
h1{
  font-size: 58px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "frutigerBold75";
  line-height: .8em;
}
```

```html
<h1><mark>Guidelines on Certification <br />and Grading</mark></h1>
```

---

*after*

```css
h1{
  font-size: 58px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "frutigerBold75";
}
mark{
  display: block;
  line-height: .8em;
}
```

```html
<h1><mark>Guidelines on Certification <br />and Grading</mark></h1>
```

Comment: Good answer, but as a minor tweak; `rem` should be used over `em`, for consistency and cannonical clarity :)

Comment: @MartinWhat do you mean? there is no `rem` or `em`

Comment: `line-height: .8em;` ==> `line-height: .8rem;`

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the issue is a font issue.
(that's the reason why if running the code snippet it's correct).

What I would suggest is to try to change the line height (manually) till you get a result you'd like.

Also, something else you could keep in mind is the internal padding (as it seems to be some from the picture you added.

unfortunately, without the same font you're using it's quite tricky to debug and help you further more.

so, to recap:

- manually adjust the line height (to be 1.1em or more, for instance)
- try with a different font
- make the padding to 0, and start adding some as required